# How to make neovim cmdline-completion suggests common matched substring?

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, cmdline

I've installed vimspector. When I type `:Vim` in the command & hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, I get all matched autocomplete suggestion like `VimspectorAbortInstall`, `VimspectorEval`, `Vim....` etc.

I'm tired to iterate that long matched list one by one to select the correct command. How to make neovim just suggest the `Vimspector` sub-word so I can just type the rest of command that I want to run?

Comment: Well, I found my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13043196/8774685

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that there are other commands that start with `:Vim` but not `:Vimspector` that are being offered in the completion, hence why it stops there.

Natively, vim offers the `:VimballList` command.  You can see with [`:h :VimballList`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_vimball.txt.html#%3AVimballList) that this comes from the `pi_vimball` standard plugin.  That page will tell you that if you do not wish to use this plugin you can disable it with the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:loaded_vimballPlugin = 1
let g:loaded_vimball = 1
```

Native vim also offers the `:Vimuntar` command.  [`:h :Vimuntar`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_tar.txt.html#%3AVimuntar) shows that this is from the `pi_tar` standard plugin which can be disabled with the following in your `vimrc`:

```
let g:loaded_tarPlugin = 1
let g:loaded_tar = 1
```

If, for whatever reason, you still wanted to use other features of those plugins but not those commands, although they are bundled with vim they are technically "user-defined" commands and can be deleted with `:delcommand VimballList` and `:delcommand Vimuntar`.

Note that I use vim, not neovim, so cannot tell if there are other commands also offered in neovim's completion menu that you would need to investigate in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Make a mapping, say,

```
nnoremap <leader>v :Vimspector
```

Note that it doesn’t end with a space or return or anything, so when you type the mapped characters you’ll be waiting at a partially filled prompt.

You could even add `<C-z>` (assuming that’s what your `wildcharm` is) to trigger completion.